# Grails 3: disable plugin but keep jar classes

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails3

Is there a way of disabling a plugin on a Grails 3 project? I am using dependencies that have Grails plugins but I just want to keep the classes that are in the dependency.

Comment: What in particular do you want to disable?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I want to disable a custom plugin that is included in a jar. I just want the jar's classes, but grails' scanning mechanism is loading the plugin too. The plugin will try to connect to an external service and I don't want that.

Comment: How to disable that will depend on how the plugin is attempting to connect to an external service.

Comment: I just want to tell grails not to run a particular plugin's init code, which I suppose is in the `doWithSpring` closure.